# How to make part of a string appear in BOLD in Java?

Tags: java, string, fonts, swt, bold

I want to make part of a String called "title" appear in BOLD in Java. The part that should appear in BOLD will be equal to another String called "searchText". This is the initialisation of the String "title". "title" is set as text of an expandItem.

```java
String title = "Schriftart";
expandItem.setText(title);
```

This is the part of the String that should appear in BOLD:

```java
String searchText = "schrift";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Only `StyledText` supports multiple styles and fonts, other controls are just plain text.

Comment: @greg-449 is there a way to use StyledText with the setText method for the expandItem?

Comment: What is `expandItem`?

Comment: @greg-449 ExpandItem​(ExpandBar parent, int style)

https://javadoc.scijava.org/Eclipse/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/ExpandItem.html

Comment: No, ExpandItem.setText is just plain text. I should have said that it is possible to use multple fonts for `Table` and `Tree` controls as well as `StyledText`, but not ExpandBar

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode [*Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols*](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/mathematical-alphanumeric-symbols/). These are symbols that consist of two parts, see: [*Supplementary Characters as Surrogates*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/supplementaryChars.html). For example:

```java
// decimal notation
char[] boldA = {55349, 56788};
// hexadecimal notation
char[] boldB = {'\uD835', '\uDDD5'};
char[] boldC = {'\uD835', '\uDDD6'};

String ABC = "ABC";
String boldABC = ABC
        // Mathematical Sans-Serif Bold Capital A
        .replace("A", String.valueOf(boldA))
        // Mathematical Sans-Serif Bold Capital B
        .replace("B", String.valueOf(boldB))
        // Mathematical Sans-Serif Bold Capital C
        .replace("C", String.valueOf(boldC));

System.out.println(ABC + " " + boldABC);
```

Output:

```
ABC
```

Output picture:

[image: ABC and boldABC]

---

<sup>Unfortunately, these bold symbols may not be available for search engines unless `A ==`  is configured.</sup>